# Webpack FileAppendPlugin for some imports

Tags: plugins, require, webpack

I have special imports in my project which loads modules by dynamically generated name, known on build time

```
var text = require('./locales/text')
```

So, I am using `FileAppendPlugin` to add locale suffix here.

```
new webpack.ResolverPlugin([
    new webpack.ResolverPlugin.FileAppendPlugin(['.'+locale + '.json'])
])
```

But it is not so good to add this suffix and try to load any missed file. Is there a way to mark only files, which really can be loaded with suffix?

If I could find a way to apply `FileAppendPlugin` only for imports, which have some special loader in prefix, like this

```
var text = require('i18n!./locales/text');
```

it would be ideal solution.

*Also, I know about `i18n-loader`, but my app architecture doesn't allow to use this*